# Segmentation fault pushing strings in a stack

Tags: c++, string, class, templates

I'm still stuck on an issue that keeps occurring with a class assignment which works with templates and Linked-List-based Stacks. I am constantly getting segmentation faults and I cannot for the life of me see why.

`main()` asks for a value to determine how many disks to play the game with, which calls `set_Discs()`, which appends "x"s to a string object `tmp_str` to represent disks for the game. This string object is then pushed onto the stack `rod[0]` (the first rod) and then it loops back. I call a `cout` to print the top stack object each time through the loop as a test and it works, so I can successfully store the string objects. However upon calling the next function `print_Game()` it does the first iteration of the for-loop (printing the first line) and goes bust again.

```
int main() {
TowerHanoi game;
size_t disc_in;

    //How many discs to be used
cout << "Welcome to Towers of Hanoi!"<< "Please enter how many discs you want to play with: " << endl;
cin >> disc_in;

game.set_Discs(disc_in);
game.print_Game();
//Ask for source and target rod

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The `set_Discs()` function:

```
    void TowerHanoi::set_Discs(size_t disc) {
    //cout << "test: " << rod[0].top() << endl;
    discs = disc;

    while (disc > 0) {
        string tmp_str;
        for (size_t i=0; i<disc; i++) {
            tmp_str.append("x");

        }
        disc--;
        rod[0].push(tmp_str);
        cout << "test: " << rod[0].top() << endl;
    }


}
```

The function `print_Game()` is a recent logical endeavour so forgive me if it's bad and under-worked. The loop adds spacing, then prints the `top` string object, then calls `pop()` (which calls `removeFromHead()` in `LinkedList.template`) to make the next string object the top object for the next time through the loop, and so on. Refer to `addToHead()`.

```
    void TowerHanoi::print_Game() {

    size_t spaces = discs;
    string topLen = rod[0].top();
    string xString;

    cout << "top length: " << topLen.length() << endl;
    for (size_t a=0; a<discs;a++) {
        LStack<string> rodCopy = rod[0];
            cout << "==="; //3 spaces
                for (size_t i=0; i<spaces-topLen.length();i++) { //add to xString
                    xString.append("=");
                }

                cout << "===" << xString << rod[0].top() << xString << endl;
                rod[0].pop(); 
                spaces--;
    }



}
```

Some relevant code from LStack.template (this is the Stack):

```
    //push
template <typename Obj>
void LStack<Obj>::push(Obj& head_in) {

    list->addToHead(head_in);
    used++;
}

//pop
template <typename Obj>
Obj LStack<Obj>::pop() {
    used--;
    return list->removeFromHead();

}
//top
template <typename Obj>
const Obj& LStack<Obj>::top() {
    return list->list_getHead();
}
```

Relevant code from LinkedList.template:

```
template <typename Item>
void LinkedList<Item>::addToHead(Item& entry) {
    node<Item>* temp = head;
    head = new node<Item>();
    head->set_data(entry);
    head->set_link(temp);

}

    template <typename Item>
const Item& LinkedList<Item>::removeFromHead() {
    node<Item>* head_copy = head; //create a copy of head
    head->set_data(head_copy->link()); //set head's data to the previous object
    return head_copy->data(); //return head's original data
}
```

Node.template:

```
    template <typename Object>
void node<Object>::set_data(const Object& new_data){
        word = new_data;
}


template <typename Object>
void node<Object>::set_link(node<Object>* new_link){
        next= new_link; 

}


template <typename Object>
void node<Object>::set_previous(node<Object>* new_prev) {
        previous = new_prev; 
}


template <typename Object>
const Object& node<Object>::data() const{  //return the word
        return word;
}


template <typename Object>
const Object& node<Object>::link() const { //return next node (const function)
        return next->data();
}


template <typename Object>
const Object& node<Object>::back() const { //return previous node (const)
        return previous->data();
}
```

Comment: what does the declaration of "rod" look like?

Comment: Are these methods all static?  No `new` operators?

Comment: `LStack<std::string> rod[2];` Cyber. There is in `addToHead()` after making the copy of head, it declares `head = new node<Item>;` this was upon the suggestion of another person Paul.

Comment: A short list: One of your problems is that the printing function modifies the game. How does *two* "rods" represent Towers of Hanoi? And why are you only using `rods[0]`? Your main problem is that you haven't tested your list class very thoroughly, though –  `removeFromHead` is both logically broken and shouldn't compile.

Comment: I'm only using rods[0] at this point because I've cut back my code to ask the program to print one rod, not all three. Once i solve that problem, i'll expand to all three. Secondly, are you able to elaborate on removeFromHead's logical brokenness? That sounds like potential helpful info. Thanks.

Comment: try to use gdb to see where the problem comes from...

Comment: @CameronO'Reilly `head->set_data(head_copy->link());` should produce a compilation error. If you attempt to "fix" it by either `head->set_link(head_copy->link());` or `head->set_data(head_copy->data());`, you have a function that does nothing and then returns the top item. (One would expect to see a modification of `head` and a `delete` in that function.)

Comment: Another potential problem is copying the entire list, like in `LStack<string> rodCopy = rod[0];`. When there are pointers involved, you have to be *very*  careful to make a deep copy of the original stack. Otherwise you will have problems when destroying the lists, like one node seemingly being a member of both lists. (You haven't shown the code for copying or destroying the stacks).

Answer (score 0):

Identifying the data being pushed on stack:

```
void TowerHanoi::set_Discs(size_t disc) 
{
    while (disc > 0) 
    {
        string tmp_str;               <-- note here, tmp_str is stack variable
        rod[0].push(tmp_str);
    }
}
```

Now, let us see the LStack::push() function:

```
//push
template <typename Obj>
void LStack<Obj>::push(Obj& head_in)   <-- note here, input to push() is pass by reference
{
    list->addToHead(head_in);
    used++;
}
```

Once, set_Discs() function call is done, the reference to the used stack variables inside this function is not valid.

This may be related to the problem of program crashing / terminating abruptly when print_Game() function is called where LStack stored data is being used.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. So does this mean that in `node::set_data()` I should declare a new string object and then say `word = new_string;`? Therefore creating a copy of tmp_str and then storing that copy instead of a reference?

Comment: @CameronO'Reilly, Yes, you are right. Also, you will have to take care of freeing allocated memory in pop(). Otherwise, I think changing the prototype of LStack::push() function to void LStack<Obj>::push(Obj head_in) will work fine. Other code remains unchanged in this case. [Passing by value/copy instead of passing by reference].

Comment: I have corrected it to a point where I don't get a segfault, however when printing, it prints the first two objects "x" and "xxx" and then copies of the second object. Like so,
  x
xxx
xxx
xxx
Could this be an error in addToHead()?